# can't access data in DB - "socket error"

Tags: neo4j

When trying to access data using cypher queries I get the following error:

`Socket error. Is the server online and have websockets open?`

I can't find anything on the internet regarding this issue, and the error message is not very specific.. Has anyone experienced this before?

**EDIT:**

This happens only when `dbms.security.auth_enabled=false` in config.

Comment: This is a known issue with RC1 which will be fixed in RC2. I'll post here if I find a work around for now. There is more info on neo4j-users group on slack :) Also an rc2 jar file.

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to `Bolt`is not accepting non-local connections and you should edit `neo4j.conf` and uncomment the line:

```
#dbms.connector.bolt.address=0.0.0.0:7687
```

See [here](https://neo4j.com/developer/kb/explanation-of-error-websocket-connection-failure/) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

This may help someone I was able to solve this problem by **uncommenting**(remove hash tags) then setting the following:

`dbms.connector.bolt.listen_address=0.0.0.0:8081` and
`dbms.connector.http.listen_address=0.0.0.0:8082`

in "**neo4j/neo4j.conf**" version:(neo4j = 3.1.4 2)